# How do you run an external program in node.js on windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating an automated web app build process with node.js on windows. I'm trying to run our code through Google closure java program. I read the documentation on child_process in the node documents. It mentions it doesnt work in windows yet. Is there a package or work around for this?

Heres the code im trying to run.

```
var _exec = require('child_process').exec;
_exec( 'java ' + '-jar '+ COMPILER_JAR +' --js '+ srcPath +' --js_output_file '+ distPath, 
    function(e){
        echo( "google closure done....");
        echo( e );
    } );
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a node package or some other work around I'm not aware of. Node is working great overall, this jar file step is a tiny portion of the overall process, and most of the team is on OSx / Linux.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have a web server app for controlling a queue of builds on windows XP and I used it to run batch files or executables without any additional packages.

I would check the error parameter on the callback and stderr as this may help you find the reason it does not work.

My example solution out of my server which I hope helps:

```
var theJobType = 'FOO';
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('Test.exe ' + theJobType, function( error, stdout, stderr) 
   {
       if ( error != null ) {
            console.log(stderr);
            // error handling & exit
       }

       // normal 

   });
```

Comment: thanks. The error I'm getting is :
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Can node not use system environment vars?

Comment: I have just tested, put my exe in a folder in the path and it was found. But I get your exact error if I put a non-existent exe name.  So seems like its an issue resolving the path/location of java.exe

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I added the full path to java.exe and its working now. thanks. Now I need to make it work on other machine configurations. java.exe wont work on OSX or Linux.